# 'Mouse capture' on a scrollbar and popup window in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid, scrollbar, childwindow

I've hit a problem with my OOB silvelight 4 applicatrion.
There is a DataGrid on the page with numer of rows, so that vertical scroll bar appears for the DataGrid.

At times I need to show a child window with a message and OK button.

If before showing the child window I am using the scroll bar, that remains selected after popup is closed. If I move mouse over scroll bar data grid scrolls.

I have tried UpdateLayout, chage visibility, rebind ItemSource. Nothing helps.

Thank you in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [UIElement.ReleaseMouseCapture()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.releasemousecapture%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method.